# Filter Subscriptions

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, subscription

On some SE sites, there is a tab called "Subscriptions" with a title of "Filter Subscriptions". What is this, and how does one use it? [Example](https://stackexchange.com/users/d67268b6-910a-49d8-810f-22b34b1081f9?tab=subscriptions).

**Edit**

I did find a link that clears it up a bit: https://stackexchange.com/filters

Comment: see also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It lists all the subscriptions to tags you have.

[image: screenshot]

When you hover a tag shown under a question, you see a popup similar to the following one.

[image: screenshot]

When you click on *subscribe*, you get emails about new questions tagged with that tag, and probably about new answers to those questions.
In your case, you are subscribed to the questions tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), and you get an email every day (in contrast with an email every 3 hours, or an email every 15 minutes).